# や in Kansai-ben when it is not だ

Tags: particles, dialects, copula, kansai-ben, anime

The following sentence occurs in The Legend of Zelda:

ナンカ　コウテ　クレヤ

(This would be なんか買うてくれや！ and was famously translated as "Buy somethin', will ya!".) From the 買うて, it's obvious he's speaking Kansai-ben, and I suspect that this usage of や is Kansai-ben as well. (I know that や is used instead of だ in Kansai-ben, but this is obviously a different usage.) But what does it mean? Does it indicate some sort of insistence?

Comment: Somebody changed the title of the question to, "is や instead of だ Kansai-ben?". I'm changing it back because that is NOT what I asked. Yes, や in place of だ is Kansai-ben. I know that. I am asking about a usage of や that appears to be Kansai-ben and IS NOT a substitute for だ.

Comment: +1 for referencing LoZ.

Comment: Why would it be こう instead of かう?

Comment: @ヤラユギ Because こうて is the te form of かう in Kansai-ben. "au" had shifted to "ou". You also see this in words like おはよう (which was originally Kansai-ben), from はやい (early/fast); the process went something like はやく -> はやう -> はよう, while Standard Japanese still uses (はやく outside of the formulaic greeting おはよう).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This actually most likely Oosaka-ben's variation of 「や」as「よ」, becoming something like:

> なんか買ってくれよ！

The usage is explained in more detail here:

http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%84?dictCode=OSAKA (Japanese)

**EDIT**

The original quote from the just in case site downtime happens:

> 「ある」が転じた「やる」の命令形「やれ」の略。言葉の終わりに付けることで、命令敬語や連用形命令語などをやわらげる働きがある。「よ」のように相手をなじる意味は含まれていない。ハンカチ忘れんと行きや、ほかしとくんなはれや、持っておいでや、など。命令形命令語などのあとにつくと乱暴な印象を持つ。持って来いや、はよせんかいや、いてもうたれや、など。

Answer (score 4):

In Kansaiben, や replaces だ and よ

Comment: That is why you never hear なんちゃらやよ right ?